# Woocommerce 'thankyou' hook only runs one function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, hook

I have two plugins that I am developing and each one has the following add action hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'dayticket_wc_order_processing', 11, 1 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_wc_order_processing', 20, 1 );
```

But unfortunately the hook only ever triggers the first instance and not the second.

I had a look around and found some solutions but none of them worked. Firstly I tried to get the secondary functions below:

```
blayney_dayticket_generate_ticket_pdf($order_id, $tickets);
blayney_alth_litfest_generate_ticket_pdf($order_id, $tickets);
```

to trigger by using one master function using the following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'ticket_download', 11, 1);
function ticket_download( $order_id ) {
  global $wp;
  $order_id = absint( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] );
  $tickets = althrop_get_tickets($order_id);

  if (is_array($tickets) && count($tickets) > 0) {
    blayney_dayticket_generate_ticket_pdf($order_id, $tickets);
    blayney_alth_litfest_generate_ticket_pdf($order_id, $tickets);
  } else { 
    echo 'No Ticket available for print!'; 
  }
  exit;
}
```

When this did not work I used a master function to call the two separate functions in each plugin by using the following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'master_function', 11, 1);
function master_function() {
        return array(custom_wc_order_processing(), dayticket_wc_order_processing());

}
```

As before it always ran the first function but never the second.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you all

EDIT:

Each plugin has this code which is relevant to the above hook:

First plugin:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'dayticket_wc_order_processing', 11, 1 );
function dayticket_wc_order_processing( $order_id ) {
    global $wp;
    $order_id = absint( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] );
    $tickets = althrop_get_tickets($order_id);

    if (is_array($tickets) && count($tickets) > 0) {
        blayney_dayticket_generate_ticket_pdf($order_id, $tickets);
    } else { 
        echo 'No Ticket available for print!'; 
    }
    exit;
}
```

Second plugin:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_wc_order_processing', 20, 1 );
function custom_wc_order_processing( $order_id ) {
    global $wp;
    $order_id = absint( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] );
    $tickets = alth_litfest_get_tickets($order_id);

    if (is_array($tickets) && count($tickets) > 0) {
        blayney_alth_litfest_generate_ticket_pdf($order_id, $tickets);
    } else { 
        echo 'No Ticket available for print!'; 
    }
    exit;
}
```

Is this ok?

Comment: You should give all related code in your question please, as it's not really testable for the moment.

Comment: Hi Sorry this is first time posting and I thought the above was enough.

Comment: First as you are using `woocommerce_thankyou` hook, `global $wp;` and `$order_id = absint( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] );` are not needed… Just use instead `if( $order_id ) return;` … Also `exit;` is not needed… You are not obliged to declare a priority and and the number of arguments used in the hook as they are optional…

Comment: So something more like this: 

`function custom_wc_order_processing( $order_id ) {
 if ($order_id) {
  return blayney_alth_litfest_generate_ticket_pdf($order_id, $tickets);
 } else { 
  echo 'No Ticket available for print!'; 
 }
}`

Comment: Yes and for the hook:  `add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_wc_order_processing' );` without the priority and the number of arguments of the function. And that for both codes.

Comment: Removing the priority and number of arguments still runs only one of the functions and breaks the page:

`add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_wc_order_processing' );
function custom_wc_order_processing( $order_id ) {
 $tickets = alth_litfest_get_tickets($order_id);
 if ($order_id) {
  return blayney_alth_litfest_generate_ticket_pdf($order_id, $tickets);
 } else { 
  echo 'No Ticket available for print!'; 
 }
}`

Comment: Ok sorry but I have never get this kind of problem… If you use the same hook 2 times with different hook priorities, both should run one after the other when the hook is triggered… So there is something else that is making trouble here, and we can only figure out things that you provide in your question code and details.

Comment: Thank you Loic that makes sense! Unfortunately I have inherited this from another developer, who unfortunately will not help, and I'm trying to work it all out! The answer below has confirmed that the two hooks work in conjunction with one another and it would appear the secondary function is causing the issue. I have added it to the question above. Thanks again for all you help and sorry if I'm not doing this right, this is my first time posting!

Comment: Don't be sorry, you are doing well on the right place. So no problem and welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have test on the localhost by passing parameter into woocommerce_thankyou hook and also without parameters but in both case its working fine.

Can you check by using below code which ensure that its working or not on your server :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'dayticket_wc_order_processing', 11, 1 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_wc_order_processing', 20, 1 );

function dayticket_wc_order_processing($order_id){

    $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/dayticket_wc_order_processing.txt","a") or die("Can't open the requested file");
    fwrite($fp, ("Order Id ".$order_id));
    fwrite($fp,("\n"));
    fclose($fp);
}

function custom_wc_order_processing($order_id){

    $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/custom_wc_order_processing.txt","a") or die("Can't open the requested file");
    fwrite($fp, ("Order Id ".$order_id));
    fwrite($fp,("\n"));
    fclose($fp);
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'my_custom_tracking' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'my_custom_tracking2' );

function my_custom_tracking($order_id){

    $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/my_custom_tracking.txt","a") or die("Can't open the requested file");
    fwrite($fp, ("Order Id ".$order_id));
    fwrite($fp,("\n"));
    fclose($fp);
}
function my_custom_tracking2($order_id){

    $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/my_custom_tracking2.txt","a") or die("Can't open the requested file");
    fwrite($fp, ("Order Id ".$order_id));
    fwrite($fp,("\n"));
    fclose($fp);
}
```

I checked on localhost and its create all the above 4 files. I have also check in two different plugin file its also working.

Comment: Hi thank you for this. On testing with the simple text output both worked fine so I can on guess that the secondary function is causing the issue.

I will add the code for the secondary function to the original question!

Comment: ok, if it help you then please mark as its relevant solutions. so it can also help other to debug or fixed error.

Comment: Ok not a problem as this has helped the initial issue. Do I just tick the icon on the left side? (Sorry I'm new)!

Comment: Yes , where it shows the up and down arrows. Click on up arrows.

Comment: I've clicked the up arrow but as my reputation is less than 15 it does not show unfortuantely.